# How can I keep mosquitoes out of my yard?

Tags: pest-control, mosquito

Since my garden is outside, and I live next to a heavily wooded area, there are quite a few mosquitoes that greet me everytime I go outside to work in my yard.

Is there something I can do to keep my yard mosquito free? Or am I doomed to using bug spray every time I step outside?

Comment: I recently tried one of the garlic/ mosquito barrier products.  It worked fantastic for about a week then we got a heavy rain and it seems to have worn off.  I'm going to try it again and see if multiple applications improve the duration.

Comment: Related: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/367/what-plants-will-deter-mosquitoes

Comment: Google DIY mosquito traps, some are quite effective.  I have found with unwanted pests, sometimes redirection to a trap is easier and more effective than complete prevention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can try and control mosquitoes.I've listed them in order of effectiveness

**Prevent them having a breeding ground and/or kill existing larvae.**

Basically most still water is perfect for mosquito larvae. We had some breeding in an old barrel full of rain and fixed the problem with a bit of washing up liquid; we noticed a huge difference within a couple of days. Bleach would also work.
If you don't want to put contaminants in the water you may be able to get them with a fine net.

**Try and encourage mosquito predators**

Bats, tadpoles, dragonflies/damselflies and some small fish will all eat them as either larvae or adults. Of these, dragon/damselflies/frogs/toads and their young will probably do the most damage to the local mozzie population.
This will probably take a lot of work so unless you already have a small pond or somewhere to shelter bats it's probably not viable.

**Plant strong smelling mosquito repellent plant species.**

The citronella geranium is probably the most well known one but there are a lot of plants that will help, particulary as mosquitoes find you by smell so having a generally fragrant garden may be a big help.
There is a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pest-repelling_plants) that may help.

As an aside I've found a product by Avon called skin-so-soft to be particularly effective at repelling mosquitoes (as well as good for your skin).

Addition: Apparently different types of mosquitoes are affected differently by various smells so some plants commonly purported to deter mosquitoes may not necessarily be effective. [This study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8723261) suggests that citronella may not even work at all.

Answer (score 1):

The breeding waters are the best place to REDUCE the numbers. I have a couple ponds , but I think mosquitoes are too smart to lay eggs in water with fish. I also have a couple rain barrels and I scoop out larva every few days to put into my aquariums , the fish go crazy. My problem area is bromeliad plants , mosquitoes breed in the retained water. To stop mosquitoes here , or anywhere , use BT ( bacillus thurengensis ). It is very safe, you can drink the water after you treat it, and it doesn't hurt fish. I understand it only becomes active in an alkaline stomach . BT is also good to kill any caterpillars in the garden.